# What is this (complex) function called?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I think I recall from my past Complex Analysis class that the function: $z \mapsto \frac{1}{2} \left ( z + z^{-1} \right )$ actually has a name. If someone could remind me of it would be fantastic.

I don't currently have access to my campus' library and a google search isn't seeming to help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean the Joukowski mapping for airfoil?

Comment: That is the one. Thank you!